# Return Parts of an Array in Postgres

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I have a column (text) in my Postgres DB (v.10) with a JSON format.
As far as i now it's has an array format.

Here is an fiddle example: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8f4ab/1)

If table1 = persons and change_type = create then i only want to return the name and firstname concatenated as one field and clear the rest of the text.

Output should be like this:

```
id  table1  did execution_date  change_type   attr      context_data
1   Persons 1   2021-01-01      Create        Name      [["+","name","Leon Bill"]]
1   Persons 2   2021-01-01      Update        Firt_name [["+","cur_nr","12345"],["+","art_cd","1"],["+","name","Leon"],["+","versand_art",null],["+","email",null],["+","firstname","Bill"],["+","code_cd",null]]
1   Users   3   2021-01-01      Create        Street    [["+","cur_nr","12345"],["+","art_cd","1"],["+","name","Leon"],["+","versand_art",null],["+","email",null],["+","firstname","Bill"],["+","code_cd",null]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disassemble json array into `SETOF` using `json_array_elements` function, then assemble it back into structure you want.

```sql
select m.*
     , case
         when m.table1 = 'Persons' and m.change_type = 'Create'
           then (
             select '[["+","name",' || to_json(string_agg(a.value->>2,' ' order by a.value->>1 desc))::text || ']]'
             from json_array_elements(m.context_data::json) a
             where a.value->>1 in ('name','firstname')
           )
         else m.context_data
       end as context_data
from mutations m
```

[modified fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8f4ab/28)

(Note:

- utilization of alphabetical ordering of names of required fields is little bit dirty, explicit `order by case` could improve readability
- resulting json is assembled from string literals as much as possible since you didn't specified if `"+"` should be taken from any of original array elements
- the `to_json()::text` is just for safety against injection

)